# How to jump to the next page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm just trying to scrape a website, but i got stuck. 
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='location of the geckodriver')
driver.get('http://kernyilvantartas.zalajaras.hu/public/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="btn"]""").click()
# the dropdown menu
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="lap"]""").click()
# click on page 2
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="lap"]/option[2]""").click()
```

After the click() it only highlights the 2nd option on the dropdown menu but doesnt jump to the next page.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to interact is a `<select>` node, so you  need to use the *Select* class and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `select_by_value()` method:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get('http://kernyilvantartas.zalajaras.hu/public/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#btn"))).click()
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[name='lap']"))))
  select.select_by_value("2")
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `select_by_visible_text()` method:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='btn']"))).click()
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='lap']"))))
  select.select_by_visible_text("2")
  ```

Comment: I have tried both way , with Firefox and Chromedriver too but the results were as earlier.  Is this work on your side?

Comment: :( I have been afraid of that. However, if you use Firefox webdriver, the manual way works fine, but the programatically doesn't. Thx for your quick help!